# UIImage stretch only a portion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

So, lets say i have this sprite:

```
mbm
bcb
mbm
```

where each letter is a portion. (m: margin; b: border, c:center)

and I want a class that is able to repeat the b's and c as long as it needs to complete the view so i get something like this:

```
mbbbbbbbbbbbbbm
bcccccccccccccb
bcccccccccccccb
bcccccccccccccb
mbbbbbbbbbbbbbm
```

Is there something that can do this already?
If it doesn't exist, any ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you not achieve this with this method ?

`-(UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight`

(see [Apple UIImage Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) )

Comment: I forgot to mention that... as I say, this is 4 corners... that method solves just the upper left corner

Comment: That method does what you want.  Although you only specify top and left it only stretches the one pixel strips just past the caps.  The effect is that only the middle portions stretch.

Answer (score 2):

We can stretch the image using the below code :- Here we need the m..m must be in same size so we stretch the middle portion

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_loginButton.png"];
    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;
    edgeInsets.left = 3.0f; //Assume it is the pixel for starting 'm'
    edgeInsets.top = 0.0f;
    edgeInsets.right = 3.0f; //Assume it is the pixel for Ending 'm'
    edgeInsets.bottom = 0.0f;
    image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
//Use this image as your controls image
```